# OSError on uploading files in Django

Tags: python, django, permissions, file-upload, file-permissions

While trying to send form with image field in it I'm getting :
`Exception Type: OSError at /user/register/

Exception Value: (13, 'Permission denied')`

Of course first thing I've checked were the permissions to my folders, and just in case set them to 777 on the whole path from '/'. Still nothing. So I've tried adding parameters to settings, which now are set like this :

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX  
'/site_media/admin/'
CACHE_BACKEND   
'locmem://'
DEFAULT_CHARSET     
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE     
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS     
777
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FS_ROOT     
'/home/rails/fandrive'
MEDIA_ROOT  
'/home/fandrive/www/fandrive/site_media'
MEDIA_URL   
'/site_media/'
PROJECT_PATH    
'/home/rails/fandrive'
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
```

Request.META :

```
CONTENT_LENGTH      
'8249'
CONTENT_TYPE    
'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------26681719213985'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/home/rails/fandrive/public'
HTTP_ACCEPT     
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET     
'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip,deflate'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-us,en;q=0.5'
HTTP_CONNECTION     
'keep-alive'
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH     
'8249'
HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE   
'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------26681719213985'
HTTP_HOST   
'example.com'
HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE     
'115'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://example.com/user/register/'
HTTP_USER_AGENT     
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6'
PATH_INFO   
u'/user/register/'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_PORT     
'52869'
REQUEST_METHOD  
'POST'
REQUEST_URI     
'/user/register/'
SCRIPT_NAME     
u''
SERVER_PROTOCOL     
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE     
'Apache'
_   
'_'
wsgi.errors     
<open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f2a6026f140>
wsgi.input  
<socket._fileobject object at 0x7f2a5cbc4848>
wsgi.multiprocess   
True
wsgi.multithread    
False
wsgi.run_once   
True
wsgi.url_scheme     
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
```

And finally my traceback :

```
Traceback:
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/registration/views.py" in register
  47.             new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/registration/backends/default/__init__.py" in register
  23.                                      request=request)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  166.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/regbackend.py" in user_created
  39.     data.save() 
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  410.         self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  483.                     values = [(f, f.get_db_prep_save(raw and getattr(self, f.attname) or f.pre_save(self, True))) for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  252.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  91.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  47.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/home/rails/fandrive/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  146.             os.makedirs(directory)
File "/bin/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/bin/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/bin/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/bin/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/bin/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/bin/python-2.6.1/lib/python2.6/os.py" in makedirs
  157.     mkdir(name, mode)
```

Any ideas what more should I check ?

UPDATE : My model

```
class UserProfile(InheritedProfile):
    def upload_path(self, field_attname):
        filename = hashlib.md5(field_attname).hexdigest()[:4] + "_" + field_attname
        return "uploads/users/%s" % (filename,)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profile')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, verbose_name="Image", blank=True, null=True)
```

I have already created 'uploads/users' folder so why is it trying to create a folder - not just a file ?

Comment: all statics stored in site-media work without any problems

Answer (score 2):

The apache use that runs your django application does not have the permission to create the folder/file in your media directory.

A quick temporary fix would be to

Go to your media folder:

`/home/fandrive/www/fandrive/site_media`

and type:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w
```

which makes your folder writeable  by all users.

This approach may not be secure. To make it secure, you can change the ownership of the folder to that user, or create a group and assign the permissions to that group.

Comment: I've had it already set to 0777. Still this doesn't solve my problem somehow :(